# Color change only after key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hex

So I have a page when you enter a HEX and it'll change to that background. The issue is, you need to press space first for some reason. My question is how can I have it so that then on the initial load, you can just enter it without pressing space? Here's my code for the background change with input

```
 $('.hex').keyup(function(){
      var a = $(this).val();
      $('#example').text(a); 
      console.log(a); 
      $('body').css('background', '#'+a);
});
```

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/lusukodo/1) a demo. Enter a hex in the first box. Nothing will happen, Then press space and enter another hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `onkeyup` event handler registering code outside the `onkeydown` event handler.

Here is the code in `onkeydown` event handler:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '32') {
     //...
     //you placed the onkeyup event handler registering code here
     //which is wrong
  }
}
//you should place the code here
$('.hex').keyup(function(){
  var a = $(this).val();
  $('#example').text(a); 
  console.log(a); 
  $('body').css('background', '#'+a);
});
```

### [Updated demo.](http://jsbin.com/lusukodo/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because everithing is in `if` statement where it checks for `if (e.keyCode == '32')` and `keyCode==32` is `space`.